# how can we share react components across repositories

Tags: reactjs, repository, bitbucket, flux

I have three different repos based o React.js and flux architecture(actions/store/utils model) on bitbucket and I want to use some UI components across these repos.
What could be the best way to achieve this, and maintain versions if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Move your components into a separate repository, google it how to set up that repo with NPM 
as a package. Then in the other repos you can install the first one as an NPM dependency. You can support multiple versions just like you probably already doing with third party npm packages.

If you want to go further you can setup your own npm registry to store all these.